# Grails 3 - Add dynamic method from plugin using traits - not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I just followed the user guide to add a dynamic method to controllers using trait from plugin.

The following are my code:

---Trait---

```
package com.ylw.gorm

trait DateTrait {
Date currentDate() {
    return new Date()
}
}
```

---TraitInjector---

```
package com.ylw.gorm

import grails.compiler.traits.TraitInjector
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic


@CompileStatic
class ControllerTraitInjector implements TraitInjector {

@Override
Class getTrait() {
    DateTrait
}

@Override
String[] getArtefactTypes() {
    ['Controller'] as String[]
}
}
```

---Controller---

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class MyDomainController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

def testTrait() {
    render "The current date is -> " + currentDate()
}

...
}
```

I am expecting the controller will know the currentDate() method from the trait. But I got the following error in the browser:

> Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.ylw.gorm.MyDomainController.currentDate() is applicable for
>   argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: create()
>       90 | methodMissing in   grails.artefact.gsp.TagLibraryInvoker$Trait$Helper
>       - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
>       12 | $tt__testTrait in com.ylw.gorm.envers.AuditedDomainController
>       93 | doInTransaction in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2
>       90 | execute   in grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate
>       1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
>       615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
>       745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

What I did wrong?

Thanks for help!
Yingliang

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown enough code to say for sure what is going wrong.

I have created a demo app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/traitplugin.

See the following:

https://github.com/jeffbrown/traitplugin/blob/b76af469a0695a449f28c43479ce60d9081c252e/datehelper/src/main/groovy/com/ylw/gorm/ControllerTraitInjector.groovy

https://github.com/jeffbrown/traitplugin/blob/b76af469a0695a449f28c43479ce60d9081c252e/datehelper/src/main/groovy/com/ylw/gorm/DateTrait.groovy

Those are copied and pasted from your example code.

The app has a controller at the following:

https://github.com/jeffbrown/traitplugin/blob/b76af469a0695a449f28c43479ce60d9081c252e/demo/grails-app/controllers/demo/MyDomainController.groovy

All of that appears to work.

Ensure that your app has a compile time dependency on the plugin.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks a lot for creating the demo app, that helped a lot! I noticed that it worked fine when I have trait created in a plugin and use that plugin in a grails app. But when I tried to create a controller within the plugin and test the trait from there, I got the error. So, is there a way to make trait works within the same project?

Comment: @Yingliang this should help to get working TraitInjector and Enhances in same project http://nimavat.me/blog/apply-groovy-ast-in-same-project-with-custom-gradle-ast-sourceset